# MAC FTP client(in /usr/bin) likes FTP server I have wrote, but FTP cafe, android app, hates it

Tags: android, ftp

What should SYST command response be ?

as response to SYST command, I have sent the message '215 MACOS Mac OS X.\r\n'.
But FTP cafe does not work. He sends me the message 'Unknown parser type:MACOS Mac OS X.'

What do I modify in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `215 UNIX Type: L8` the first field (UNIX) being a well-known name from the [official list of reserved names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc943#page-26). The [FTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-33) does not specify the "Type:" string, but it seems what other FTP servers send, so it would be wise to follow their example (especially if you expect quirky clients). L8 specifies that the server uses a local, 8-bit format. Again, I'd suggest to go with what most FTP servers do.